# knockout modal loading issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to display a modal when user click on a contact Title.
I have an array of 50 contacts, I'm displaying all elements :

```
Natha Delarue
CEO Sikka
sikka@mail.com(work) 
+33 5 99 31 86 36 (work) 
Sikka.com (work) 
http://sikka.com (work) 

Paul kalbernner
...
```

I would like when I click on contact Title (name, firstname) to load a modal to print another content (signature for example, twitter...)

here is my code :
modal :

```
 <div class="modal fade hide" data-bind="modal: viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.selected">
        <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h3>Edit Record</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
     <div> Contenu signature </div>
        </div>

       </div>
```

to display all informations :

```
 <div id="retrievedContactsDiv" data-bind="foreach: viewModel.MoreContacts.contacts()">

  <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.contactTitle(), click:  viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.selected"></a>

<!-- ko foreach: $data.organizations() -->


   .......

    <!-- ko foreach: $data.emails() -->

        .....
```

selected initialization

```
viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport = {
selected: ko.observable(), }
```

Comment: and your question is ..?

Comment: my modal is not displayed